# check if value exists in array not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script that works fine where it activates the button and select option based on some restrictions.

```
<script>
var update_selectopt=function(){
$("tr").each(function(){
  if($("input[type='checkbox']", this).is(":checked")){
    $('#select',this).removeAttr('disabled');
  }
  else{
    $('#select',this).attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
});
};

function updateSubmitButtonState(){

var enableableLineCount= 0;
$("tr").each(function(){

if( isEnableableLine( this ) )
  enableableLineCount++;
});

if( enableableLineCount > 0 )
   $('[type="submit"]').removeAttr("disabled");
else
   $('[type="submit"]').attr("disabled","disabled");


function isEnableableLine( tr ){

if( 
    $("input[type='checkbox']", tr).is(":checked") && 
    $("select option[value='no_action']:selected", tr ).length == 0 
)
  return true;
else
  return false;
  }
}

$(update_selectopt);
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click",update_selectopt);

$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click",updateSubmitButtonState );
$("select").on("change",updateSubmitButtonState );
</script>
```

But when I add the code for checking the value in array and popping an alert box if not, it is not working,also breaking the code - making the button inactive all time, select options are all active all the time. Also, I am little confused where to put the code to keep the button inactive all the time until all the conditions are not true.

Complete script

```
<script>

var state_list_swap=["AVAILABLE","IMPAIRED"]
var state_list_shut=["ERROR"]
var state_list_scan=["SUSPENDED"]

var update_selectopt=function(){
$("tr").each(function(){
  if($("input[type='checkbox']", this).is(":checked")){
    $('#select',this).removeAttr('disabled');
  }
  else{
    $('#select',this).attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
});
};

function updateSubmitButtonState(){

var enableableLineCount= 0;
$("tr").each(function(){

if( isEnableableLine( this ) )
  enableableLineCount++;
});

if( enableableLineCount > 0 )
   $('[type="submit"]').removeAttr("disabled");
else
   $('[type="submit"]').attr("disabled","disabled");


function isEnableableLine( tr ){

if( 
    $("input[type='checkbox']", tr).is(":checked") && 
    $("select option[value='no_action']:selected", tr ).length == 0 
)
  return true;
else
  return false;
 }
}

$(update_selectopt);
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click",update_selectopt);

$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click",updateSubmitButtonState );
$("select").on("change",updateSubmitButtonState );


$("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
 $("tr").each(function(){
  if (
    $("select option[value='swap']:selected",tr)
    ){
        var cells=$(this).find('td');
        $(cells).each(function(){
            if (jQuery.inArray($(this).text(),state_list_swap)!=-1){
              alert('swap is allowed only with "AVAILABLE","IMPAIRED" states');
            } 
          });
    }
    else if(
        $("select option[value='scan']:selected",tr)
      ){
          var cells=$(this).find('td');
          $(cells).each(function(){
              if (jQuery.inArray($(this).text(),state_list_scan)!=-1){
                alert('scan is allowed only with "SUSPENDED');
              }  
            });

        } 
    else if(
        $("select option[value='shut']:selected",tr)
      ){
          var cells=$(this).find('td');
          $(cells).each(function(){
              if (jQuery.inArray($(this).text(),state_list_shut)!=-1){
                alert('shut is allowed only with "ERROR" states');
              }  
            });

        } 

  }    

});

</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the console?

Comment: ^ that, there's a missing parentheses for the last `each` loop

Comment: I would reformat your question, placing your problem at the beginning and using smaller code snippets of the problem code. This would make it easier for others to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these fixes:

```
<script>

    var state_list_swap=["AVAILABLE","IMPAIRED"]
    var state_list_shut=["ERROR"]
    var state_list_scan=["SUSPENDED"]

    var update_selectopt=function(){
        $("tr").each(function(){
            if($("input[type='checkbox']", this).is(":checked")){
                $('#select',this).removeAttr('disabled');
            }
            else{
                $('#select',this).attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
        });
    };

    function updateSubmitButtonState(){

        var enableableLineCount= 0;
        $("tr").each(function(){
            if( isEnableableLine( this ) ){
                enableableLineCount++;
            }
        });

        if( enableableLineCount > 0 ){
            $('[type="submit"]').removeAttr("disabled");
        }else{
            $('[type="submit"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
        }

        function isEnableableLine( tr ){
            if( 
                $("input[type='checkbox']", tr).is(":checked") && 
                $("select option[value='no_action']:selected", tr ).length == 0 
            ){
                return true;
            }else{ 
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    //WHATS THIS 
    //$(update_selectopt);

    $("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", update_selectopt);

    $("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", updateSubmitButtonState );

    $("select").on("change",updateSubmitButtonState );


    $("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
        //  inside this, you had no reference to what 'tr' was
        //  --added it as the element reference in the .each loop
        $("tr").each(function (ind, tr) {
            if ($("select option[value='swap']:selected", tr)) {
                var cells = $(this).find('td');
                $(cells).each(function (index, element) {
                    if (jQuery.inArray($(element).text(), state_list_swap) != -1) {
                        alert('swap is allowed only with "AVAILABLE","IMPAIRED" states');
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (
                $("select option[value='scan']:selected", tr)
              ) {
                var cells = $(this).find('td');
                $(cells).each(function (index, element) {
                    if (jQuery.inArray($(element).text(), state_list_scan) != -1) {
                        alert('scan is allowed only with "SUSPENDED');
                    }
                });

            }
            else if (
                $("select option[value='shut']:selected", tr)
              ) {
                var cells = $(this).find('td');
                $(cells).each(function (index, element) {
                    if (jQuery.inArray($(element).text(), state_list_shut) != -1) {
                        alert('shut is allowed only with "ERROR" states');
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    });

</script>
```